# Show string variable on mouse hover

Tags: php, hover

I have something like this:

```
<?php
$show_title = urlencode(row_Something['text']);
echo '<td title='.$show_title.'>;
?>
```

When I hover mouse over the cell of the table it shows ***row_Something['text']*** which is like ***The house is red***.
If I use only

```
$show_title = (row_Something['text']);
```

I get only ***The***.

If I use 
`$show_title = urlencode(row_Something['text'])`
I get ***The+house+is+red***.
What I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What is `row_Something`? Is that a variable? Should it not have the dollar ($) sign in front of it, i.e. `$show_title = $row_Something['text'];`?

Comment: Also, you’re looking for `htmlspecialchars` to escape your variable, not `urlencode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the generated HTML look valid to you?

```
<td title=The house is red>
```

Try actually using quotes:

```
echo '<td title="'.htmlspecialchars($row_Something['text']).'">';
```

In future, always View Source when attempting to debug PHP results.

Comment: Right! Thank you for your time! In the future I will also try to extract only the problem from the whole code. I have a lot of if, else, variables parsed... and so on. Thank you again!!!